# Tuning Laravel+Nginx in Debian. Routing

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5

Does not work even

```
Route::get ('foo', function () {
     return 'Hello World';
});
```

in the web.php file - returns 404
My url http://localhost/project/public/foo
Laravel 5.4

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /srv/www;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Any help for me.

Comment: project/public should be ignored/replaced to whatever is your route. if it's in api, its api/foo for example

Comment: what i need to do how to fix this?
I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root is in the wrong directory for laravel.

it should be /srv/www/project/public

Comment: I fixed it, but still returns 404 Not Found

Comment: try_files $uri $uri/ =404; should be try_files $uri $uri/;

Comment: I fix and...500 Internal Server Error

Comment: 500 internal server error - that a coding/programming issue.. you need to check the logs either nginx or php-fpm.

Comment: error.log: 2018/04/05 03:01:48 [error] 1974#1974: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "////////////", client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Need root /srv/www/project/public/; and try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;